# Foursquare Realtime User API

Tags: api, tomcat, real-time, foursquare

I have a problem with my app that I want to use as sink for the push POST requests. I programmed it in Java as a straight forward servlet, I verified that I can send POST requests to it, but the test push from my consumer’s admin page says 404.

Is it possible that I can’t run the push sink on another port than 80? My secure Tomcat port is 8888. I don’t see any calls from the Foursquare servers in my Tomcat access log.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Realtime API self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729743/realtime-api-self-signed-certificate) 4sq seems currently not to be able to send POST requests to other ports than 443 (standard SSL).

I worked around this by using the mod_jk connector to let Apache2 send requests to a special directory directly to Tomcat7. This works for me.